# How to loop through JSON object?

Tags: json

How can we loop through given JSON object to traverse all its properties:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var students =  '{"name": "John", "age": 30, "subjects": [{ "name": "IT", "marks": 85 }, { "name": "Maths", "marks": 75 }, { "name": "English", "marks": 60 }]}';

var myObj = JSON.parse(students);
alert(myObj.name);                  
alert(myObj.age);                   
alert(myObj.subjects[0]['name']);                   
alert(myObj.subjects[0]['marks']);                  
alert(myObj.subjects[1]['name']);                   
alert(myObj.subjects[1]['marks']);                  
alert(myObj.subjects[2]['name']);                   
alert(myObj.subjects[2]['marks']);                  
</script>
```

You can see I am accessing nested "subject" properties by using its index and property name. But the code becomes lengthy to traverse each items. To avoid it, I am wondering how to loop (e.g. for in loop) through by writing single line of code to access all its properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(students);
for(var index = 0; index < myObj.subjects.length; index++) {                 
  alert(myObj.subjects[index]['name']);                   
  alert(myObj.subjects[index]['marks']);                  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Each` function to iterate the each subjects

```js
var students =  '{"name": "John", "age": 30, "subjects": [{ "name": "IT", "marks": 85 }, { "name": "Maths", "marks": 75 }, { "name": "English", "marks": 60 }]}';

var myObj = JSON.parse(students);


$.each(myObj['subjects'], function(index, value) {
    console.log(value['name']+" "+ value['marks']);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using stringify

```
var myObj = JSON.stringify(students);
for(var index=0;index < myObj.subjects.length;index++) {
  alert ( myObj.subjects[index] );
}
```

Comment: ERROR: TypeError: myObj.subjects is undefined